# jQuery disabled button with checkbox issue

Tags: jquery, button, checkbox

I have the following code which enables a button when the checkbox is checked.

http://jsfiddle.net/ERfWz/1/

The following is a snippet from the code I have in my HTML page. It's much the same however for some reason it's not working. I think I may have been looking at it for too long.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
  $('#agree').click(function() {
    var satisfied = $('#agree:checked').val();
    if (satisfied != undefined) $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    else $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});​
</script>



<form>
    <table>
    <td colspan="5"><input type="checkbox" id="agree" name="agree" />I have read and agree to the terms and 

    conditions</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" align="center"><input name="Submit" type="submit" id="submit" disabled value="I Accept. 

    Submit"/>
                  <label>
                      <input name="reset" type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="ip" value=" echo $REMOTE_ADDR; " />
                  </label></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>*Required Fields</td>
                    <td colspan="4"></td>
                  </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td colspan="5"><h3></h3>
                     <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Comment: Are the {}'s after the if () optional? I've always done if () {}.

Comment: @orolo: Yes, they're optional. It's good practice to use them anyway, but if they are not there, the standard is to assume that the next line (and only the next line) is the only thing in the block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also set `disabled` with `true` and `false`, so you can simplify it down to:

```
$(function() {
  $('#agree').change(function() {
    $('#submit').attr('disabled', !this.checked);
  });
});​
```

[Test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Hudt8/1/), note there was also some invalid markup going on resulting in some cross-browser inconsistencies, it should look something like this:

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tr><td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="agree">I agree Terms and Conditions</td></tr>
    <tr><td align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" disabled></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Also the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) method's a bit better here, to ensure you have the correct state.

Comment: +1 Didn't know that! Does this also work for other `x="x"` attributes like `readonly` etc?

Comment: @BoltClock's - Yup, `selected` as well, each of those are booleans in the DOM :)

Comment: @Nick, that's perfect. Thank you. I will check this as the right answer once the time limit is up.

Comment: @Nick: Will you run into any IE issues with change? I know I've had problems with IE and the change event in the past, so I'm just wondering if it would apply here.

Comment: @Jeff - Nope, that's with bubbling, and in < 1.4.2 versions :)

Comment: @Nick: Interesting. I was having an issue in IE8 using 1.4.2 with the `change` event not updating a `select`. Good to know, though. =)