# JavaScript enable button when checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I need to have this button disabled, and when the user checks a checkbox it needs to be enabled its just not working for me at all, the button stays disabled, i know the onclick is calling the script because i placed an alert in the script and it does alert me....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goFurther(){

if (document.getElementById("ID").checked == true)
document.getElementById("Calculate").disabled = false;
else
document.getElementById("Calculate").disabled = true;
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
input[disabled]
{
   color:Gray; text-decoration:none;
}
</style>



<CFOUTPUT query = "qGetOpenItemsTrans">
    <TR>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">
          <input type="checkbox" name = "chkbx" id='#ID#' value="#seq_claim_id#"           onClick="goFurther()" unchecked = 0   >
        </TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Inventory_Date#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#seq_claim_id#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Month_Closed#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Amount_Rcvd_by_FRG#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Commission_Amt#</TD>
        <TD ALIGN = "CENTER">#Net_Recovery#</TD>
    </TR>
```

```
<INPUT TYPE ="Button" NAME = "Calculate" VALUE = "Calculate" onClick = "FormSubmit();"     style="height:35px; width:150px; font-size:medium; font-weight:bold; color:green;" disabled >
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery disabled button with checkbox issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858022/jquery-disabled-button-with-checkbox-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to your `name` attribute needing replaced by (or added with) `id` attibute, your function is also trying to get an element with the ID value of `id`. However, your IDs are dynamic via your query loop. Pass the clicked element itself to the `goFurther` function so you have direct reference to the checked element.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkbx" id='#ID#' value="#seq_claim_id#" onClick="goFurther(this)" >

<INPUT TYPE="Button" id="Calculate" VALUE="Calculate" onClick="FormSubmit();" style="height:35px; width:150px; font-size:medium; font-weight:bold; color:green;" disabled >

    <script>function goFurther(elem){
if (elem.checked == true)
document.getElementById("Calculate").disabled = false;
else
document.getElementById("Calculate").disabled = true;
}</script>
```

You may also simplify your function further by doing the following:

```
function goFurther(elem){
    document.getElementById("Calculate").disabled = !elem.checked;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To your styling issue. this is due to how CSS works. You have a `disabled` style selector defined in your CSS, but your in-line style is set to `color: green` which will always take presidence over any defined stylesheets.

```
<style>
input#Calculate {
    color:green;
}
input#Calculate[disabled]
{
   color:Gray; text-decoration:none;
}
</style>

<INPUT TYPE="Button" id="Calculate" VALUE="Calculate" onClick="FormSubmit();" style="height:35px; width:150px; font-size:medium; font-weight:bold;" disabled >
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfect the only thing I cant get the style of the button to change. depending if its disabled i want it that gray style

Comment: Make sure you test this thoroughly.  The checkbox has an onClick event but it's possible to navigate html forms and check/uncheck checkboxes using only a keyboard.

Comment: @DanBracuk, even using the keyboard, hitting the spacebar to check the box also fires the event. Agreed though regarding testing this thoroughly.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling document.getElementById("Calculate"), but your button does not have an id of "Calculate".

```
id="Calculate"
```

Comment: good catch, i did add that but still does disabled when i checkmark the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be confused with the attributes "name" and "id".

The attribute "id" give you access to an element (tag)

The attribute "name" defines on form child elements (like input, button) the name of the value.

In your case you should change to

```
...
<input type="checkbox" name = "chkbx" id='ID' 
  onClick="goFurther(this); return false;">
...


<script type="text/javascript">
 function goFurther(self){
    document.getElementById("Calculate").disabled = !self.checked;
 }
 </script>
```

I guess this way it much easier to read (but still untested)

```
<INPUT TYPE ="Button" ID = "Calculate" NAME = "Calculate" VALUE = "Calculate"
 onClick = "FormSubmit();" style="height:35px; width:150px; font-size:medium;
 font-weight:bold; color:green;" disabled >
```