# How to enable Onclick <Button> when Check box clicked PHP

Tags: javascript

I Want to enable my Button , once the checkbox has been checked,
i have recently searching this a lot but all solution where for the **form or input tag ,** 
I have a Button

```
<button onclick= buttonOnClick(); onmouseover="mouseOver();" onmouseout="mouseOut();" >Click here <i id="rtb" class="fa fa-moly-square rtb"></i></button>
```

and the check box code :

```
 <div class="page__toggle">
      <label class="toggle">
        <input class="toggle__input" type="checkbox" >
        <span class="toggle__label">
          <span class="toggle__text">Check Me!</span>
        </span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this question has nothing to do with PHP, it's a pure Javascript question

Comment: You need JavaScript (client side) for that. This is unrelated to php. An easy way to do this would be using jQuery for this. Look it up. There are many examples on how to change the DOM on a click event.

Comment: ops , iam new to coding , please  suggest me the script to enable the button ?

Comment: as for the question, you say you want to enable the button when the checkbox is checked - yet the button does not appear to start off disabled. It's also not clear whether you want the enabling to be a one-off event when the user first checks the checkbox, or if each checkbox click should toggle the button's state.

Comment: @DanielKhan all wehere for forms like this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263494/javascript-enable-button-when-checkbox-checked  , i need for the <button> <button> tag

Comment: @AmritShikawat - I just checked your link, it looks like an *exact* duplicate of your question. The fact that that referred to an `<input type="button">` rather than a `<button>` doesn't matter, you can still target it the same way.

Comment: @RobinZigmond i tried the "disabled"  attribute on my button , but when i click on check box nothing get validated ,  i want something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/bluz/peans/  but for the <button> atr

Comment: @RobinZigmond can u please provide me a full code , cuz i tried the disabled attribute on my buttom but with using the script and check box it is not getting validated

Comment: @AmritShikawat that JSFiddle does exactly what you want, and as I said, the fact that it uses a slightly different element affects nothing. That code just targets an element with a particular ID - it can be any element. It's completely trivial to change that so it works for your case, because you don't even have to touch the JS, just edit the HTML a little bit!

Answer (score 1):

The approach here would be to add an `Event listener` to your `HTML element` so that you can react to when the user interacts with the checkbox, then you can update the state of the `disabled` property in the `button` element.

```js
const checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
const button = document.getElementById('button');

const toggleButtonState = function (event) {
  button.disabled = !event.target.checked;
}

checkbox.addEventListener('change', toggleButtonState)
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button" disabled>A button</button>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
  <small>Toggle Button</small>
</label>
```

Comment: i added the script below the <head> tag  `<script>
const checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
const button = document.getElementById('ytb');

const toggleButtonState = function (event) {
  button.disabled = !event.target.checked;
}

checkbox.addEventListener('change', toggleButtonState)
</script>   `                                                                                                                                                                 the button is disabled as usaual but after checking the check box , it doesn't gets enabled.

Comment: Note that the HTML elements in your code need to have the `id="button"` and `id="checkbox"` attributes, these are just examples and should be called something more distinctive in your code. @AmritShikawat

Comment: please check the links i did it correctly , 1.the button  code , 2.check box code , 3. the script by you https://ibb.co/DLgx6wg
https://ibb.co/SPfqtz1
https://ibb.co/r6FMTRF

Comment: @AmritShikawat you've copied Daniel's Javascript code, but not his HTML - so this isn't going to work, as the two belong together.

Comment: see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ua2s5xow/) I just made by literally copy-pasting Daniel's code. (The one you posted earlier in the comments also works - the code is slightly different but it's the same idea.)

Comment: @AmritShikawat make sure you understand the solution rather than just doing copy paste, what the code is doing is finding each `HTML element` using javascript's `document api`. It uses `findElementById` to locate the `HTML` elements by their `id` attribute, and uses that reference to  "subscribe" a function that runs every time the `change` event is triggered.