# Spring client validation on a non DB field

Tags: spring, forms, validation

I have a spring flow project. On the form I want to add a check box, like "I confirm that I have provided correct details" and want to stop the flow if this check box is not checked. I don't want to add this as a DB field (validation through that is pretty simple). I cant find a way to validate the check box at client side. Any examples/options are appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858022/jquery-disabled-button-with-checkbox-issue

Comment: I was looking for something integrated with spring framework. There are numerous ways to do it with jquery and other available js libs.

Answer (score 0):

`jsr-303` or `jsr-349` are the standards for bean validation, and is the reference yoou're looking for, from a high point of view. Youcan start reading from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_Validation

When it comes to implement this in Spring, you have to annotate the parameter passed to the MVC handler method as `@Valid` and implement a `Validator`. The best example you could look at, initially, is the Spring official documentation:http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Comment: This is again related to bean validation, this would require a field on the entity AFAIK. I want a client side front end validation.

Comment: @Saba it doesn't. `bean`and `entity` are two different things.

Comment: @Saba PS: if you want to validate **client-side** there is already one asnwer: Javascript. Spring performs validation on server side. Though, if you just want the error to be diplayed to the user, Spring provides a way to do so, after validation. To remain completely on client side, there is jQuery which supports data validation.

Comment: thanks for your answer, beans and entity are different I agree, but then I don't want things to go to server side. The form I was working on is multi-part and the submit button is shared between different types of forms. So I was finding it difficult to do it on the client side. I will re-look at bean validation.